# Show that this algorithm does not work for determining convex polygons

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry

**Context**

Consider this algorithm. If the set $\{\angle p_ip_{i+1}p_{i+2} : i=0,...,n-1\}$  does not contain left and right turns, output "yes the polygon is convex"; otherwise, "no".

**My answer**

Consider this nonsimple polygon having 4 vertices; the algorithm above will output "yes" as the set of points does not contain both left and right turns, yet the polygon is not convex. Is this a good counterexample rendering the above algorithm incorrect?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer does not seem like a valid counterexample. You present a face for which the algorithm will return 'yes, it is convex' and then assert that the shape is not convex--a fact which is not clear upon inspection.

Comment: @Kaya, I don't get what you mean :(, isn't the presented polygon not convex?

Comment: The face in the interior seems to be a a quadrilateral with straight sides. The only way I know of for one of these to be non-convex is if there is some interior angle greater than $\pi$ radians. The one you present seems like each of the four interior angles is approximately $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple counterexample is a pentagram (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram). It contains right turns (if you go in clockwise direction) only, but it is not convex. The above algorithm will incorrectly say pentagram is a convex polygon. It's actually a complex polygon.

In other words, algorithm might fail if the input polygon is complex.